# GI-Completeness of graph isomorphism with connected graphs

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, np-complete, graph-isomorphism, graph-connectivity

The Wikipedia page for Graph Isomorphism [lists connected graphs as GI-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem#GI-complete_classes_of_graphs). The citation has a paywall, and I have not been able to find any NP-complete algorithms for isomorphism of connected graphs.

Is this correct? Where can I find such an algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GI-completeness is different from NP-completeness. (It is strongly believed that graph isomorphism is not NP-complete, though we don't yet know a polynomial-time algorithm.) A *class of graphs* is GI-complete if testing if graphs from this class are isomorphic is "as hard as" testing if general graphs are isomorphic.

Here is why graph isomorphism for connected graphs is GI-complete. Suppose that you have an algorithm that tests if two connected graphs are isomorphic, and you are given two graphs $G_1, G_2$ that are both *not* connected. You can still test them for isomorphism using your algorithm: let $H_i$ be a graph constructed from $G_i$ by adding a single vertex connected to all others. Then $H_1$ and $H_2$ are connected, so we can test if they are isomorphic using your algorithm.

But $H_1 \cong H_2$ if and only if $G_1 \cong G_2$: the extra vertices we added are the only ones connected to all others, so they must be paired together in any isomorphism between $H_1$ and $H_2$, and deleting them both would produce an isomorphism between $G_1$ and $G_2$. Therefore your algorithm becomes a general algorithm for graph isomorphism.